# Fatal error: Cannot break/continue 1 level - проблема с циклом while

Tags: php

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ";",'"')) !== FALSE) {

include(DIR_CMS."/get_data.php");

}
```

содержание get_data.php

```
if(empty($data[0]))
    continue;
```

Здравствуйте.
Подскажите, почему через инклуд я получаю ошибку, а если убрать инклуд и прописать условие в цикл, то ошибки нет ?

Comment: Даже если бы это заработало, я бы не советовал вам так делать

Answer (score 1):

Синтаксический анализатор ломается, когда видит `continue` на верхнем уровне.

Он же не в курсе, куда вы его собираетесь инклудить.

В общем, не нужно так делать. Файл в php - самостоятельная единица интерпретации.

Answer (score 0):

Дополню @vp_arth

Если `get_data.php` содержит всё, что Вы написали, лучше сделать так:

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ";",'"')) !== FALSE) {

    if(empty($data[0]))
        continue;

}
```